# Constructing sets involving predicates. Let $P(x),Q(x)$ be predicates over a set $X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, notation

Let $X$ be a set and $P(x),Q(x)$ be predicates over $X$. Consider the sets $$Y = \{y\in X\mid P(y)\}$$ $$Z = \{z\in X\mid Q(z)\}$$
Complete the following sentences with quantified propositional formulas involving P, Q

1. $Y \subseteq Z$ if and only if
2. $Y \cap Z = \emptyset$ if and only if
3. $Y \cup Z = X$ if and only if

### Questions

- What does the set notation look like for: Let $X$ be a set and $P(x),Q(x)$ be predicates over $X$ ?
- I'm given that the statement $Y\cap Z = X \Leftrightarrow\forall x \in X [P(x) \land Q(x)]$, but I don't why this is; I get $Y\cap Z = \{(y,z)\in X\mid P(y)\land Q(z)\}$. What is the proof for this equivalence? How do I go from one to the other?

Comment: Why would you like to express "Let $X$ be a set and $P(x)$,$Q(x)$ be predicates over $X$" in set notation? As for the second question $Y\cap Z = \{x \in X \mid P(x) \land Q(x)\}$, i.e. $(y,z)\in X$ would mean that $X$ is a set of pairs, which might not be true.

Comment: @dtldarek I want to visualize the set $X$ like the given sets $Y$ and $Z$ because the problem's wording is confusing and I don't know what it means. For the 2nd part isn't $Y\cap Z=\{y\in X\mid P(y)\}\land\{z\in X\mid Q(z)\}=\{(y,z)\in X\mid P(y)\land Q(z)\}$ or am I thinking about it in the wrong way?

Comment: You are mixing notation, operators and ideas. For example the connective $\land$ takes two Boolean values (i.e. truth/falsehood), while a similar operator that would take two sets is $\cap$. In other words writing $\{1,2\} \land \{2,3,4\}$ is meaningless, because $\land$ is not defined to operate on sets and "does not know" what to do with them. Also $(y,z)$ is a pair which is a different type of an element, perhaps you wanted to write $\{x \in X \mid x = y \land x = z \land P(y) \land Q(z)\}$?

Answer (score 1):

We must use the definitions:

> $Y \subseteq Z \equiv \forall x(x \in Y \rightarrow x \in Z)$.

So, if $Y = \{y \in X : P(y) \}$ and $Z = \{z \in X : Q(z) \}$, we have that :

> $Y = \{y : y \in X \land P(y) \}$,

and similarly for $Z$.

> $Y \subseteq Z$ iff $\forall x((x \in X \land P(x)) \rightarrow Q(x))$.
>
> $Y \cap Z = \emptyset$ iff $\forall x((x \in X \land P(x)) \rightarrow \lnot Q(x))$.
>
> $Y \cup Z = X$ iff $\forall x((x \in X \rightarrow P(x) \lor Q(x))$;

this shows that $X \subseteq Y \cup Z$, but by contsruction, being $Y$ and $Z$ subsets of $X$, so is $Y \cup Z$.